# Row limiting clause - FETCH FIRST in SQL Developer tool

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-fetch

When i tried to execute this statement:

```
 select salary,DEPARTMENT_ID from  EMPLOYEES  order by 1 fetch first 15 rows only;
```

I got an error as follows:

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

I executed this in SQL Developer (17.3.1), if that matters.

Comment: What version of Oracle is your database on? The client and version of that shouldn't matter (esp. as you're using the current version of SQL Developer). The database server version does matter though.

Comment: Please run this command: `select * from v$version;` and append it's result to the question. My guess is that a version of your database is earlier than 12c, but this clause `fetch first ...` was introduced in 12c and it doesn't work in earlier versions.

Comment: As others have pointed out: the version of the SQL _client_ is irrelevant because the SQL is executed by the server - and the version of that matters